# How we can change whole website in other language in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am new user i want to change my small website into urdu/arabic.dropdown shows multiple languages any one can guide me? This should be done in asp.net MVC website.

Comment: have you tried something

Comment: if your website is static then google plugin in enough

Answer (score 0):

.NET uses CultureInfo classes to define languages and text content, this is quite a wide question, which englobes a lot of things, starting by understanding the concept of internationalization in .NET

Start here

http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/understanding-internationalization-in-aspnet-mvc